# Mudar a instância da base de dados

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, banco-de-dados, connectionstring

Eu estou a fazer um projeto em MVC e o meu problema é que a minha base de dados é criada automaticamente na instância "localdb", mas eu queria que ela fosse criada na minha instância que eu criei no SQL Server.

Existe a possibilidade de mudar isto? E, se existe, posso mudar logo quando crio o projeto?

Comment: Pelo que entendi você tem que arrumar sua connection string, coloque ela na pergunta para vermos como ela está definida e ajudarmos a editar ela para você

Comment: É só mudar no web.config

Comment: O meu problema é mesmo esse, antes quando crio o projeto, ele cria me a base de dados no localdb e no web config nao tem nenhuma connection string, e ele cria na mesma a base de dados, ou seja, se eu puser a connection string para o sqlserver mal comece o projeto ele já não me vai criar no localdb e sim no sqlserver? porque o que eu fazia era o seguinte, eu criava os modelos e gerava as views e ia ver em qual das instâncias ele tinha criado a base de dados e so depois é que punha a connection string no webconfig, ou seja tinha sempre duas bases de dados iguais uma em cada instância e as vezes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abra o arquivo **`web.config`** e procure pela seção `connectionStrings`.

Lá, provavelmente, vai ter um tag `add` que contém a *string* de conexão que aponta para o LocalDB.

Altere-a para que ela fique parecida com isto — obviamente você vai precisar usar os dados de conexão do seu SQL Server.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" 
       connectionString="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Nome-Banco;Uid=User;Pwd=Senha;PersistSecurityInfo=True" 
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```